# Database documentation with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2.37 and I find it a great tool for database development.

I did create all the tables, fields and relationships and I also did document (adding a comment for every field with their functionality, same for relationships and tables).

I would like to export just this documentation. I mean, not the SQL scripts but the metadata I did put for the table and its fields.

Something like:

Table: Customers

Comment: Represent the customers of the system

Fields:

id (INTEGER not null, unique): The customer unique identifier

name (VARCHAR[100] not null, unique): The customer name

...

Does anybody know if extracting such a report is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have the community edition of MySQL Workbench?

I would think that documenting the database by CREATE statements would be close enough to what you are trying to achieve.

Select all tables in your schema (SQL Editor View), right-click and select 'Send to SQL Editor' -> Create Statement.

You could then save a file which consists of every table in your database.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `Code` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Name` char(52) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Continent` enum('Asia','Europe','North America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Asia',
  `Region` char(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SurfaceArea` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `IndepYear` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LifeExpectancy` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GNP` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GNPOld` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LocalName` char(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GovernmentForm` char(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HeadOfState` char(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Capital` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Code2` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `countrylanguage` (
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Language` char(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IsOfficial` enum('T','F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  `Percentage` float(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CountryCode`,`Language`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

If you happen to have the standard edition (commercial) there are some features which might be right up your alley :

[image]

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
I used the information_schema database to extract the metadata from databases that is used. 
You can use tables: 
TABLES - Metadata about all tables in server.
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE - Metadata about all keys used.
COLUMNS - Metadata about all columns.

You can get a lot a information there, also you can get your comments if you had commented columns and tables.
To get content from base tables from a selected database you can run this query. Notice that i selected some field that satisfied my needs.

To get information about tables from a selected database, you can run this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_schema' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

To get information about columns from a selected table, you can run this:

```
SELECT COL.COLUMN_NAME,COL.COLUMN_COMMENT,COL.COLUMN_TYPE,COL.IS_NULLABLE
  FROM COLUMNS COL LEFT JOIN KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU
  ON COL.TABLE_NAME = KCU.TABLE_NAME AND COL.COLUMN_NAME = KCU.COLUMN_NAME
  WHERE COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_schema' AND COL.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
  ORDER BY COL.TABLE_NAME,COL.ORDINAL_POSITION ,COL.COLUMN_NAME
```